# How do you output extra lines near a specific string pattern in powershell 2.0?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm working on a Powershell script for Server log monitoring purpose. Basically, I need to look into the log file and check the date where next to a specific string pattern.

With the following code, I was only able to locate the string pattern, but I need couple more lines near this string patter.

```
$fPath = "C:\temp\imlog.txt"
Get-Content $fPath | Where-Object {$_.Contains('ORA-')}
```

An Example of the log:

> ORA-03135: connection lost contact
>
> Tue Sep 26 12:49:29 2017
>
> ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms
>
> Sat Sep 30 16:29:22 2017

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Post the relevant lines from the logs file.

Comment: Edit your question to add an example of your log file.

Comment: I can't remember if Select-String had the -Context parameter in 2.0 or not. If it did though, then this would do it. Start with ***Get-Help Select-String***

Comment: @EBGreen is correct that the `-Context` parameter of `Select-String` is what you are looking for (that parameter did exist in 2.0).

Comment: Thanks to @Bill_Stewart and EBGreen, the problem is solved now.

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to @EBGreen and @Bill_Stewart.

the following script will do the job.

```
#Define log file path
$fPath = "C:\temp\imlog.txt"

#Output Context near string pattern
Get-Content $fPath | Select-String -Patter 'ORA-' -Context 2 | Select -Last 1
```

Thanks to all.